# How to retain the content of the variable on every call in java

Tags: java, linked-list

Hi am developing a linked list in java.

In my system there will one master node where the master node will distribute the incoming request to one of its slave node. 
In order to make use of cache memory, i initialized a linked list for each node (where all the content will be maintained in the master node).

I update the linked list of respective node before the node process any query (so that i can find what are request recently processed by the respective nodes).

**But the problem is, at an instance when i try to find the content of the linked list its empty**. Even when i try to add new content, it creates the list newly and then add the content. I think the list is created newly every time when i access the java file containing the linkedlist implementation.

**Is it possible to retain the content of the linked list and update the linked list with the previous content.** Is their any inbuilt function in java to retain the state of the variable or where can i initialize the list in order to achieve what i expect.

```
My code is as follow
    import LinkedList.QueueImplement;

public class Node {

protected LinkedList<String> list;

public Node(String address, String serviceName) {
  this.list=new LinkedList<String>();
}

 public void addlist(String data) {
    list.add(data);
}
}
```

Comment: I feel I must ask precisely what it is you're trying to achieve. I assume this is some sort of academic exercise, from the reinvention going on?

Comment: Will be easier if you show us your code.

Comment: My linked list implementation will be in separate java file. I want to update that linked list with its previous content. But the actual problem is the list bet reinitialized every time when i access the particular java file.

Comment: Why you do not want to use `java.util.LinkedList`? Or at least take a look how is it built and implement your own?

Comment: Your "every time I access the java file" suggests that you don't know enough about what's going on to really benefit from an answer to your direct plea for help with the (also suggestively bizarre) solution you have in mind.  Ask a better question about your problem.

Comment: i used java.util.LinkedList in the file linedList.QueueImplement. So am importing that particular file to access the queue.

Comment: So, if you know about LinkedList why are you going to implement your own?

Comment: Please read my question properly.. My question is not about implementation of linked list. Its about how to prevent the content of the linked list between each call..

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is just that every `Node` constructs its own `LinkedList`, as is clearly shown in the little code we see. If the variable `list` were marked `static`, and constructed at its declaration rather than in the constructor, then all `Node`s would share a single `LinkedList`, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Sorry! I don't want to implement single LinkedList for every nodes. Each node should have their own linked list to store the query that, that particular node has processed.